# Whatsapp suddenly crashed and device got unresponsive

Tags: samsung-galaxy-a5

My Samsung Galaxy A5 2016 is of full of storage and I am talking to my friend through whatsapp, and it got crashed and stop working. I can't receive calls or get out of whatsapp or even turn the phone off. What should I do now?

Comment: Holding the power button down for 15-30 seconds doesn't work? Then uninstall some stuff or remove files to clear up space.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the power button until something happens. When my S4 becomes unresponsive, a long-press of about 10 seconds eventually gets the phone off.